# Multiple Customer Databases plus Global Customers

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am developing a (potentially) large-scale tracking software that tracks customer data, along with tickets that are created for tasks associated with said customers. This system is written entirely in PHP, and the database is MySQL.

The system currently supports multiple "locations" (stores for example), and each has its own table for customer data (in the same database, each database can be host to a whole different business' installation). For example:

#### store1_customers

```
customer_id | customer_firstname | customer_lastname
----------------------------------------------------
          1 |               John |               Doe
          2 |               Bill |               Bob
```

#### store2_customers

```
customer_id | customer_firstname | customer_lastname
----------------------------------------------------
          1 |               Jill |             Smith
          2 |              Jimmy |            Person
```

This works great for keeping locations separate for different business needs. However, we are running into the need to have "global" customers for other instances that can be accessed from any location, while keeping other customers separate.

The two options I can think of are to either make a new "global_customers" table that can then be pulled from separately, or to merge *all* of the data into one large table.

I have concerns with both methods. The first would require a new column in every table that references the customer to determine which customer table to pull from. For example, `store1_tickets` would have to know whether to pull the customer ID of `1` from `store1_customers` or from `global_customers`. This seems to be a bit dirty, and I think would present problems with trying to do my multiple `JOIN` queries.

The second method of making one giant table concerns me in two ways: the first being the size of the table (each table so far can have potentially 20k+ records, and there are 7 locations for just one particular installation of the "software"). I know this point may be moot due to how MySQL works and can handle it. The second concern is merging the existing data. I see it being a nightmare since each table has a 1-20k customer ID, and I would have to have some way of changing thousands upon thousands of existing records in other tables to match the new numbering of this table.

Is there a better way, or more proper way of accomplishing this? I'm sorry if this question does seem subjective, but it does come down to a database problem and how to handle the data in a reasonable way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge all the data into one large table. That is how databases are designed to be used.

For data migration, you will end up with new Keys, there is no way around that. You could, however, add a new column to store the 'legacy' ID. This is just some of the pain assoicatied with normalizing a database. Take the pain now rahter than presisting with a sub-optimal database design.

Customer type would be another column within the cusotmer table, probably (but depending on your requirements) this would be a FK to a `CustomerType` table.

Comment: How do you propose that I solve the issue of merging the tables? I have multiple tables for each location that would need to have references changed, and the base `customer_id` would need to be changed for every existing customer from each table. Also, what is the best way of distinguishing what type of customer each entry is? With a new column I assume?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the suggestion about the legacy ID, that may help immensely with the migration. My team has agreed that normalizing the tables would be the best option in the long run before the project gets considerably larger. I guess I just have to do this super carefully...